# Return function output to component in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

AOA,
I want to return the output of `useAuth`.the output will be returned to `ProtectedRoute` component and as it is will be returned to `layout.js`. let me know if you need more info

Private Route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
let ast=null;

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {



useEffect(() => {
async function useAuth () {
    let as=null;
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    //const user = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    //const user = cookies.get("authToken");
    const _id="633e9ed97968510b2689851b";


    if (user) {

        const config = {
      
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        };
        try{
            
        const {data}=await axios.post(
            `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/Veri`,
        {
            _id
        },
        config
          );

       console.log("data" +data.email);
       if(data.email){
       
        return (<Outlet />)
       }
       else{
        console.log(<Outlet />);
        return <Navigate to="authentication/card/login" />;
       }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log("Error   ");
            ast=false;
            return <Navigate to="authentication/card/login" />;
        }
          
    } 
    
    else {
        ast=false;
        return <Navigate to="authentication/card/login" />
    }
}



useAuth() ; 

  }, []);
```

layout.js

```
<Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
    <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
      {/*Dashboard*/}
      <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="dashboard/analytics" element={<Analytics />} />
      <Route path="dashboard/crm" element={<Crm />} />
      <Route path="dashboard/saas" element={<Saas />} />
      <Route path="dashboard/e-commerce" element={<Ecommerce />} />
</Route>
    </Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a component returned from useEffect instead you should be using a state for this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useEffect, useState, useNavigate } from 'react';
let ast=null;

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
      
  useEffect(() => {
    let as=null;
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const _id="633e9ed97968510b2689851b";

    //IDK where the **user** comes from
    if (user) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        };
        try{
          const {data}=await axios.post(
            `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/Veri`,
          {
            _id
          },
          config
          );
          console.log("data" ,data.email);
          if(data.email){
            setAuthenticated(true);
          }
          else{
             setAuthenticated(false);
          }
        }
        catch(error){
          console.log("Error   ");
          ast=false;
          setAuthenticated(false);
        }
    }
    else {
      ast=false;
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }
  , []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(authenticated==false){
      navigate("authentication/card/login");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    authenticated==true ? <Outlet/> : null
  )
// You can replace the null with some loader.
}
```